# Why does the use of sections and parts generate bbl errors?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, parts

A little background: I've been out of LaTeX for quite some time and I'm working myself back into it. I might be as well be overlooking something obvious... Thanks for your understanding :-)

As soon as I use `\part` or `\addsec` command, the compiler produces errors. When these commands are removed, the compiler runs fine. Does anyone have a clue what the reason is and how to fix it? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=10pt,twoside,twocolumn,pagesize,DIV=15,headsepline,titlepage,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,english,ngerman,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\languagechange}[3]{%
  %\wlog{Lang: #3}%
  \newcommand{#1}{%
    \fontencoding{#2}\selectfont
    \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#3}%
  }%
}
\languagechange{\de}{T1}{ngerman}
\languagechange{\en}{T1}{english}
\languagechange{\pl}{T1}{polish}
\languagechange{\vn}{T5}{vietnamese}

\newcommand{\textfsf}{\sffamily\bfseries\selectfont}
\newcommand{\textksf}{\sffamily\itshape\small\selectfont}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.8em}}
%\makeatother

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\description{\raggedright}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.2ex}
\flushbottom

\clearscrheadings
\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{\pl KSIĄŻKA\\ \vn SÁCH}
\subtitle{\pl DO CZYTANIA\\ \vn ĐỌC}
\author{\pl Johnny\\ \vn Giăng}
\date{}
\publishers{\pl wydawcy\\ \copyright{} 2020}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
\mainmatter


\begin{description}
\item[\pl first item] \vn còn, mà
\item[\pl second item] \vn mua dài hạn
\end{description}
\addsec{\pl A}


%\include{plvn}
%\include{vnpl}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Try commenting out the `\addsec{\pl A}` quite at the bottom and it will compile just fine. Here's my error log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\bbl@fixname #1->\begingroup \def \bbl@tempe 
                                             {l@}\edef \bbl@tempd {\noexpand...
l.63 \addsec{\pl A}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Argument of \bbl@tempd has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.63 \addsec{\pl A}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\noexpand \@ifundefined {\noexpand \bbl@tempe \languagename }}\bbl@tempd \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \bbl@tempd was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.63 \addsec{\pl A}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Undefined control sequence.
\bbl@fixname #1->\begingroup \def \bbl@tempe 
                                             {l@}\edef \bbl@tempd {\noexpand...
l.63 \addsec{\pl A}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Argument of \bbl@tempd has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.63 \addsec{\pl A}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\noexpand \@ifundefined {\noexpand \bbl@tempe \languagename }}\bbl@tempd \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \bbl@tempd was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.63 \addsec{\pl A}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 68.
Runaway argument?
{\protect \bbl@restore@actives \protect \fontencoding  {T1}\protect \selectfont  \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \bbl@foreign@x was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.68 \backmatter

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@begin@tempboxa ...begingroup #2\color@endgroup }
                                                  \def \width {\wd \@tempbox...
l.68 \backmatter

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Can anyone reproduce these errors?

Comment: Could you please add some background info on the intended use of `\de`, `\en` `\pl`  and `\vn`?

Comment: @leandriis It is a multilanguage document. There is thousands of language changes throughout it. To make switching easier these commands have been created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your language commands are not robust. You should either use `\addsec{\protect\pl ...}` or define them as robust:

```
\newcommand{\languagechange}[3]{%
  %\wlog{Lang: #3}%
  \newcommand{#1}{}% to check that we don't overwrite an existing command
  \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{%
    \fontencoding{#2}\selectfont
    \csname otherlanguage*\endcsname{#3}%
  }%
}
```

Don't use utf8x if possible, use utf8 instead. In a current LaTeX there is even no need to load inputenc, utf8 is the default encoding.

Comment: Great solution! BTW, not loading `inputenc` generates a warning: `Package babel Warning: No input encoding specified for Vietnamese on input line 146.`

Comment: Report the warning to the maintainer of vietnamese.ldf, it should adapt to the new default.